# On Hover Clipping

Tags: css

I have a line of text inclosed in div tags. What I would like to happen is when the mouse hovers over the text, it to be changed to the font color red, but have an appearance effect from left to right. Right now, it does not stick when the user hovers over the raw text.
There might be a better way on doing this, so please, any suggestions welcomed.

Thank You!

```html
<style>
[base]{ width:auto;  height: auto; position:absolute;  transition: all 0.2s ease-out; } 
[highlight]{ clip-path: inset(0px 100% 0px 0px);  color:red;  } 
[raw]:hover ~ [highlight]{   clip-path: inset(0px 0px 0px 0px); color:white;    }   
</style>

<div raw >
<div >The line of text is going to be red when hovered</div>    
</div>

<div base highlight style="width:auto">
The line of text is going to be red when hovered
</div>
```

Comment: your last css rule setting the color to white is the problem.

Comment: Perfect. Now the problem I am facing is the hover only works when the pointer is directly on the letters. Inbetween the hover does not work even though is it applied on the parent.

Comment: I'd open a new question for that.